# I'm trying to write a Javascript code that checks if text input form is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm building a to-do app with javascript. Everything works perfectly except the validation. I have written some few lines of codes to check if User inputs any value. However it doesnt work. I have pasted my code below. Thanks

```js
var inputTask = $("#inputTask").val();
 var submitTask = $("#display-taskList");
 var taskList = $("#taskList");
 var submitTask = $("#submit-task");

 
 submitTask.click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  if(inputTask === ''){
   alert("Add A Task")
  }
  else if(inputTask != ''){
   $("ol").append("<li>" + $("#inputTask").val() + "<span class='close'>" + "x" +"</span>" + "</li>" );
  }
  /*$("ol").append("<li>" + $("#inputTask").val() + "<span class='close'>" + "x" +"</span>" + "</li>" );
  $("#inputTask").val("");*/

   });



     $("ol").click(function() {
          $("li").addClass('strike')
         });
```

```css
html,body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
  body{
   background: #F3904F; /* fallback for old browsers */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #F3904F , #3B4371); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
   background: linear-gradient(to left, #F3904F , #3B4371); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
        
  }

  #center-block {
      width:600px;
      height: 100%;
      padding:10px;
      background: #F3904F; /* fallback for old browsers */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #F3904F , #3B4371); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
   background: linear-gradient(to left, #F3904F , #3B4371); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  }

  #inputTask{
  width: 530px;
  height: 44px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font: 16px arial,sans-serif;
     line-height: 34px;
     height: 34px !important;
     margin-top: 20px;
     margin-bottom: 25px
     ;
  }

  input[type=text]{
   background-color: #3B4371;
   font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  }

  input[type=text]:focus {
     background-color: #fff;
     font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
     border: 3px solid #555;: 
  }

  #title{
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  }

  hr{
   width: 50;
  }

  button{
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: default;
     font-family: arial,sans-serif;
     font-size: 15px;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin: 5px 30px 10px 30px;
     min-width: 54px;
     height: 30px;
     padding: 0 16px;
     text-align: center;
  }

  ol > li {
   color: #fff;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   font-size: 20px;
   background-color: #A9A9A9;
   margin-top: 5px;
   padding-left: 5px;
   padding-top: 5px;
   padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
  
  
  li:hover{
   background: #808080;
   cursor: pointer;
  }

  .strike{
   text-decoration: line-through;
  }

  .close{
   color: red;
   font-size: 13px;
   float: right;
   padding-right: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="center-block">
<div class="row">
 <form>
  <h1 class="text-center" id="title">Simple to-Do list</h1>
  <hr width="50%">
  <input type="text" id="inputTask" name="" placeholder="Title...">
  <button id="submit-task">Hit Me!</button>
  <button id="submit-task">Clear List</button>
  </div>
 
 <div id="display-taskList">
  <h3 style="color: #fff; font-family: 'Kanit';"> Task to accomplish</h3> 
  <ol></ol>
  </div>
 </form> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are declaring your `inputTask` variable right when the document initializes. It is retrieving a value from your input right when the page loads, and at that time the input box is always empty.

To fix this, move your declaration:

`var inputTask = $("#inputTask").val();`

inside of your `submitTask.click` event.

```js
 var submitTask = $("#display-taskList");
 var taskList = $("#taskList");
 var submitTask = $("#submit-task");

 
 submitTask.click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var inputTask = $("#inputTask").val();
  if(inputTask === ''){
   alert("Add A Task");
  }
  else if(inputTask != ''){
   $("ol").append("<li>" + $("#inputTask").val() + "<span class='close'>" + "x" +"</span>" + "</li>" );
  }
  /*$("ol").append("<li>" + $("#inputTask").val() + "<span class='close'>" + "x" +"</span>" + "</li>" );
  $("#inputTask").val("");*/

   });



     $("ol").click(function() {
          $("li").addClass('strike')
         });
```

```css
html,body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
  body{
   background: #F3904F; /* fallback for old browsers */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #F3904F , #3B4371); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
   background: linear-gradient(to left, #F3904F , #3B4371); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
        
  }

  #center-block {
      width:600px;
      height: 100%;
      padding:10px;
      background: #F3904F; /* fallback for old browsers */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #F3904F , #3B4371); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
   background: linear-gradient(to left, #F3904F , #3B4371); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  }

  #inputTask{
  width: 530px;
  height: 44px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font: 16px arial,sans-serif;
     line-height: 34px;
     height: 34px !important;
     margin-top: 20px;
     margin-bottom: 25px
     ;
  }

  input[type=text]{
   background-color: #3B4371;
   font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  }

  input[type=text]:focus {
     background-color: #fff;
     font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
     border: 3px solid #555;: 
  }

  #title{
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  }

  hr{
   width: 50;
  }

  button{
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: default;
     font-family: arial,sans-serif;
     font-size: 15px;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin: 5px 30px 10px 30px;
     min-width: 54px;
     height: 30px;
     padding: 0 16px;
     text-align: center;
  }

  ol > li {
   color: #fff;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   font-size: 20px;
   background-color: #A9A9A9;
   margin-top: 5px;
   padding-left: 5px;
   padding-top: 5px;
   padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
  
  
  li:hover{
   background: #808080;
   cursor: pointer;
  }

  .strike{
   text-decoration: line-through;
  }

  .close{
   color: red;
   font-size: 13px;
   float: right;
   padding-right: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="center-block">
<div class="row">
 <form>
  <h1 class="text-center" id="title">Simple to-Do list</h1>
  <hr width="50%">
  <input type="text" id="inputTask" name="" placeholder="Title...">
  <button id="submit-task">Hit Me!</button>
  <button id="submit-task">Clear List</button>
  </div>
 
 <div id="display-taskList">
  <h3 style="color: #fff; font-family: 'Kanit';"> Task to accomplish</h3> 
  <ol></ol>
  </div>
 </form> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It fixed it.. I only followed the global scope principle. I will watch out next time